# How to fetch multiple GET URLs at once

Tags: javascript, json, api, get, fetch-api

```
fetch(`./User.json`, { method: "get" })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data =>
    data.results.forEach(result => (list.innerHTML += template(result)))
)
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I want to add some json data.  what's the solution.
That's my code.

Comment: Create an array of promises and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to process the returned data.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all requests to complete, regardless of their response status, then [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is an excellent choice

```js
// handy "get" shortcut with error handling
const get = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url) // "GET" is the default method
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
  }
  return res.json()
}

const urls = ["./Foo.json", "./Bar.json", "./Baz.json"]

Promise.allSettled(urls.map(get)).then(responses => {
  const data = responses
    .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
    .map(({ value }) => value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#syntax) to get the values of the fetch calls once all the promises have resolved, you'd get the values in an array which you can destruct as shown below

```js
    Promise.all([fetch(`./User.json`, { method: "get" }).then(response => response.json())]), fetch(`./Products.json`, { method: "get" }).then(response => response.json())]).then([users, products]=>
    users.results.forEach(result => (list.innerHTML += template(result)))
)
```